# open a project in android studio from my git repository

Tags: git, android-studio

I did clone from bitbucket.org to a project repository. I want to open this project in android studio, but when I try to open the project from the repository in my computer, the project appears like a directory not like a project ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbHWh.jpg)without the android-studio-icon). How can I open the project from my repository in the computer to continue working on it and to be able to do push/pull to the git in the future?

[The project name is "Appaw":](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbHWh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

From Android Studio

File->Open and then select your Appaw folder.

Comment: This what I did and got the problem I described in the question. I did't get my Appaw as a project. It seems like I don't have all the file related to this project.